# I have an override for \texttt to prevent line breaks and add a box, but it still breaking up the word

Tags: macros, line-breaking, typewriter

I have the following override:

```
% override the inline code styling to show a gray highlight box
\let\oldTexttt\texttt
\renewcommand{\texttt}[1]{%
  \begin{RaggedRight}%
  \sethlcolor{codegray}%
  \ttfamily\hl{#1}%
  \end{RaggedRight}%
}
```

But I still have words that are supposed to be in the gray box getting split between lines.  The words are commands like: selectpicture and listpictures.  In one case the first word is split sel at the end of one line and ectpicture at the start of the next.  In another case the second word is split listpic at the end of one line and tures at the start of the next.  I need to have these words not getting split.

NOTE: I am not trying to prevent all word wrapping/line breaking throughout the document, just the ones in `\texttt`.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. It is always better if you provide your problems as a minimal, but compilable document (*minimal working example*, MWE). This way others see what class and packages they need to take into account and can also test there solution with no extra effort required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  I needed to put an `\mbox` in there.

Problem solved.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/162330)

Comment: @naphaneal: While short, this is still a acceptable self-answer, while (for me obviously) does not belong to the question post.

Comment: @JonBelanger: Note that with `\mbox` you don't need `RaggedRight` anylonger, as it forces *restricted horizontal mode* and left/right adjustments are only for *paragraph mode*.

Comment: @MartinScharrer didn't notice that. will pay more attention next time.

Answer (score 1):

Your `\begin{RaggedRight}...\end{RaggedRight}` does nothing at all, except limiting the scope of `\ttfamily`, because `\end{RaggedRight}` just ends the scope where `\RaggedRight` is in force. The paragraph will be formed in exactly the same way with or without `\RaggedRight`.

I cannot recommend redefining `\texttt`. If you want to do it nonetheless, then use the proper way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul,ragged2e,xcolor,letltxmacro}

\colorlet{codegray}{black!30}

\LetLtxMacro\oldTexttt\texttt % useless?
\let\texttt\relax

\DeclareRobustCommand{\texttt}[1]{%
  \mbox{\sethlcolor{codegray}\ttfamily\hl{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

We have some nonsense text in order
to show what happens \texttt{abc def ghi jkl} and if this
splits across lines we're happy.

\end{document}
```

Adding `\mbox` makes line breaks impossible between items in the argument.

However, that's *not* what `\texttt` is expected to do. A different macro
would be better for this and other reasons, mainly that a new name would add *semantics* to your typescript.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul,ragged2e,xcolor,letltxmacro}

\colorlet{codegray}{black!30}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\code}[1]{%
  \mbox{\sethlcolor{codegray}\ttfamily\hl{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

We have some nonsense text in order
to show what happens \code{abc def ghi jkl} and if this
splits across lines we're happy.

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer above.  I have one issue where long commands do not wrap and run off the side of the page.  I need to be able to prevent hyphenating, but allow for word wrapping.  Is there an easier solution for this?